# Тестирование функции в Си

Tags: c, тестирование

Как проверить как ведет себя функция на разных данных в Си? Скажем, есть функция, которая определяет по трём сторонам, что это треугольник.

```
void tr(float a, float b, float c) {
  if(a+b>c && b+c>a && a+c>b) { printf("Треугольник!"); }
}
```

Предполагаю, что нужна функция, которая будет вызывать функцию tr() с разными данными.

**UPD**. Поправка по совету [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd).

```
int tr(float a, float b, float c) {
  if(c<=0 || b<=0 || a<=0) { return 2; }
  if(a+b>c && b+c>a && a+c>b) { return 0; } else { return 1; }
}
```

Покажите пример теста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, необходимо различать blackbox- и whitebox-тестирование: имеет ли право тестирующий код опираться на знание того, как устроена функция?

В вашем случае функция не является *чистой*: она ничего не выдаёт, а сама изменяет внешний объект (пишет на консоль). Это неверно, такие функции тестировать невозможно. Перепишите функцию так, чтобы она выдавала результат, а уж в какой форме и куда его выводить (и выводить ли вовсе), пусть заботится внешний код.

Когда переделаете, можно будет тестировать. В любом случае, blackbox или whitebox, стоит проверить, как работает функция на различных входных данных:

1. Неприятные частные случаи: если одна из длин сторон — ноль или отрицательная, или специальное значение NaN, или бесконечность, как ведёт себя функция? Какое значение она возвращает? Сообщает ли она о недопустимых входных данных?
2. Величины сторон удовлетворяют неравенству треугольника: сообщает ли функция, что из данных трёх сторон можно построить треугольник? Попробуйте разный порядок аргументов: не изменится ли ответ?
3. Величины сторон не удовлетворяют неравенству треугольника, одна из сторон равна сумме двух других. Сообщает ли функция, что из данных трёх сторон нельзя построить треугольник? Попробуйте разный порядок аргументов: сумма на первом месте, на втором и на третьем.
4. Величины сторон не удовлетворяют неравенству треугольника, одна из сторон больше сумме двух других. Сообщает ли функция, что из данных трёх сторон нельзя построить треугольник?

---

Пример теста, реализующего проверку 3:

```
// где-то в начале программы: srand(time(NULL)); или что-то похожее

float getRandomFloat(float from, float to)
{
    assert(from < to);
    return from + (to - from) * (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}

int getRandomInt(int from, int to)
{
    assert(from < to);
    return (int)(from + (to - from + 1) * (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
}

int test3()
{
    float addend1 = getRandomFloat(1, FLT_MAX/2);
    float addend2 = getRandomFloat(1, FLT_MAX/2);
    float sum = addend1 + addend2;
    if (tr(addend1, addend2, sum) != 0)
        return 0; // test failed
    if (tr(addend1, sum, addend2) != 0)
        return 0; // test failed
    if (tr(sum, addend1, addend2) != 0)
        return 0; // test failed
    return 1; // test passed
}
```

Пример теста, реализующего часть проверок пункта 1:

```
#include <math.h>

int test1_NaN()
{
    float args[3];
    args[0] = getRandomFloat(1, FLT_MAX);
    args[1] = getRandomFloat(1, FLT_MAX);
    args[2] = getRandomFloat(1, FLT_MAX);

    int numberOfNanEntries = getRandomInt(1, 3);
    // тут надо бы выборку, но мне лень
    switch (numberOfNanEntries)
    {
    case 1:
        args[getRandomInt(0, 2)] = NAN;
        break;
    case 2:
        {
        int goodIdx = getRandomInt(0, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) if (i != goodIdx) args[i] = NAN;
        }
    case 3:
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) args[i] = NAN;
    }

    if (tr(args[0], args[1], args[2]) != 2)
        return 0; // test failed
    return 1; // test passed
}
```

Аналогичные тесты на пункт 2 (например, если оба слагаемых больше `FLT_MAX/2`, код должен правильно работать.

---

```
struct test_entry {
    const char* description;
    int (*test)();
} entries[] = {
    { "NaN arguments", test1_NaN },
    { "One argument is a sum of other two", test3 }
    // ...
};
const size_t number_of_entries = sizeof(entries) / sizeof(*entries);

int test_coordinator(char*** failed_test_descriptions)
{
    char** failed_descriptions = malloc(number_of_entries * sizeof(char*));
    int failed_curr_idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_entries; i++)
    {
        if (!entries[i]->test())
            failed_descriptions[failed_curr_idx++] = entries[i].description;
    }
    if (!failed_curr_idx)
    {
        *failed_test_descriptions = NULL;
        free(failed_descriptions);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *failed_test_descriptions =
                realloc(failed_descriptions, failed_curr_idx * sizeof(char*));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD: Поправил. Покажите пример теста.

Comment: @VladD: Теперь она возвращает 2, если входные данные не верные.

Comment: @VladD: Покажите, как пользоваться результатами такого теста и расскажите немного о том как оформлять тесты, где много функций. Скажем, у меня есть Функция, которая использует результаты этой функции. Как для неё написать тест.

Надо каждый пункт в отдельную функцию выделять?

Comment: @2202100: Ну, вам нужна координирующая функция, которая запустит по одной все тестирующие функции и проверит, что возвращённые результаты все равны 1.

Выделить каждый пункт в отдельную функцию — хорошая вещь для модульности. Можно ещё присобачить к функции описание того, что именно она проверяет, чтобы можно было сообщать, что именно сломалось.

Таким образом, получается целый тестовый фреймворк. (Кстати, можно взять и готовый, их полно.)

Comment: @2202100: добавил примерный драйвер тестов. Надеюсь, не налажал с управлением памятью.

Comment: @VladD, все-таки утверждение, что функции, которые пишут в stdout, тестировать *невозможно* слишком сильное.

Другой вопрос, что на данном этапе освоения программирования перехватить и проанализировать вывод (а также отловить zerodivide, segmentationfault и т.п.) может быть и сложновато для ТС.

Но, пусть знает, что такие штуки можно запрограммировать и думает (изучает) каким образом.

--

@2202100, самое главное в тестировании, это не проверка, как ведет себя функция, а поиск такого набора данных на котором она "ломается".

Comment: @avp: С другой стороны, чтобы тестировать такое, надо знать сложные, системно-зависимые технические подробности. А отловить UB (например, segfault) корректно вообще теоретически невозможно, так что я бы и не пытался. Может, я избалован высокоуровневыми языками?

Comment: @VladD, тестирующие и тестируемые функции можно запустить в отдельном процессе и посмотреть результат wait(). 

Если тестируемая функция пишет в stdout (но, stdin не читает), то можно просто запустить весь тестируемый .exe через popen() (кстати, это будет отдельный процесс).

Если тестируемая функция хочет вести диалог stdin/stdout, то можно приладить forkpty()...

Comment: @avp: Угу, хорошая идея насчёт выноса в отдельный процесс.

Answer (score 1):

Я категорически против возвращения ошибок через данные. Исповедую философию программирования "Let it crush". Если таких данных в функцию поступать не должно, то лучше это выяснить сразу!

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

bool is_triangle(double a, double b, double b)
{
    assert(isnormal(a) && isnormal(b) && isnormal(c));
    assert(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0);
    return (a + b > c) && (b + c > a) && (c + a > b);
}
```

Вообще-то хорошо бы выбрать какой-нибудь тестовый фреймворк, чтобы не мучиться. Однако данную конкретную функцию тестировать не имеет смысла, потому что её запись совпадает с формулой. Это всё равно что тестировать учебник математики. Разве что пару тривиальных примеров реализовать, только чтобы удостовериться, что мы не сделали опечатку.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool result = is_triangle(3, 4, 5)
               && is_triangle(3, 3, 3)
               && is_triangle(10, 10, 15)
               && is_triangle(119, 120, 169)
               && !is_triangle(100, 100, 1000);

    puts( result? "OK" : "FAIL");

    return 0;
}
```